# Move projects from an older version of TeamCity server to a newer version

Tags: server, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous

I have two TeamCity Servers which are running on different software versions: one server is running "TeamCity Enterprise 9.1.7" whereas the other Server is running "TeamCity Professional 7.0.2". What is the best way to perform a migration. I want to transfer the projects that exist on Server 7.0.2 to the Server 9.1.7.

I would be very grateful if you could provide me with the steps to undertake.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of TC versions between 7.0.2 and 9.1.7, more than 4 years of updates: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Previous+Releases+Downloads

First of all, you should make a backup using maintainDB tool, then you can try to migrate from major to major version and test the results:

**UPDATE:** base on vlad-p53's comment you can migrate directly form 7.0.2 to 9.1.7, so, just follow the tutorial [A Step by Step Guide to Migrating a TeamCity Instance from One Server to Another](https://blogs.endjin.com/2013/07/a-step-by-step-guide-to-migrating-a-teamcity-instance-from-one-server-to-another/).

---

- 7.0.2 to 8.0 and test the results.
- 8.0 to 9.0 and test the results
- 9.0 to 9.1.7

If a migration to a major version does not work, you can try a previous versions and repeat the process.

Each release has a release note that explains if there is a migration issue, I recommend to you to [read them](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Previous+Releases+Downloads).

To each migration you can follow the steps of this tutorial: [A Step by Step Guide to Migrating a TeamCity Instance from One Server to Another](https://blogs.endjin.com/2013/07/a-step-by-step-guide-to-migrating-a-teamcity-instance-from-one-server-to-another/).

Comment: Migration could be done directly from 7.0.2 to 9.1.7 without any intermediate steps.

Comment: Another addition: After migration done, you could export all data and then import it to another server (with same version, 9.1.7) via [Projects Import feature](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Projects+Import)